# Pycharm debugging - save variable using watches

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, watch

Is there a way to save the variable names in watches? Every time I debug, the list goes empty and I have to put in the same variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the *Debug script*, there is **Watches** button.

Reading from a [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debug-tool-window-watches.html) about Watches:

> While the Evaluate Expression command on the context menu of the Variables pane enables you to see one expression at a time, the Watches pane shows multiple expressions that **persist** from one debug session to another, until you remove them.

To add expression to persist from one session to another, simply click **+** sign and type the name of variable. Then, when you debug again, you will see it again being evaluated until you remove it (using **-** sign).

[image]

Comment: for some reason, some times it's there sometimes it's not. I haven't figure out why yet. I started out being able to do that... then somehow i couldn't and now I can again. probably user error on my part.

Comment: Yeah interface is wierd when watches are around variables. You can click last icon in column below the + sign to separate watches to the second tab to see more clearly.